# even matches lost using match on a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to match a *xxx pattern such as "*test", "*love" "*anything" (like hashtag)

i basically tried:

```
"*aaa *eee *rrr *ttt".match(/(\s|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(\s|$)/img)
```

returns only odd logical matches: "*aaa " and "*rrr "

When matching, i guess engine "marks" the whole matching digits as "used" and so are removed from testing to next block. and so, what can be the "nothing" digit, because starting "^" is not there, and there is nothing before second match.

Does anyone have an idea to fix it?

Comment: i tried to uncapture the \s|^ or \s|$ using
"*aaa *eee *rrr *ttt".match(/(?:\s|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(?:\s|$)/img)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
/(?:^|\s)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(?=$|\s)/gim
```

[See demo here](http://scriptular.com/#%28?%3a%5E%7C%5Cs%29%28%5C%2a%5Ba-z0-9%5D%7B3,150%7D%29%28?=%24%7C%5Cs%29%7C%7C%7C%7Cgim%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22%2aaaa%20%2aeee%20%2arrr%20%2attt%20%2axxx@%20hhh%2aiii%20%2auuu%2aooo%20%2awww%22%5D).

Usage:

```
var match, regex = /(?:^|\s)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(?=$|\s)/gim
while (match = regex.exec("*aaa *eee *rrr *ttt *xxx@ hhh*iii *uuu*ooo *www")) {
    console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Output (matched "tags"):

```
*aaa
*eee
*rrr
*ttt
*www
```

Comment: One thing to note here is that, like the OP's solution, any 'tag' followed by punctuation (e.g. `.!?:;`) won't be captured by your regular expression.  That's the reason I switched the OP's `\s|$` for a `\b` in my answer.

Comment: @AndyE With word boundary (`\b`) the regex matches `*xxx@` so... no. If the OP wanted to match punctuation, he'd have to do it explicitly: `(?:^|\s)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(?=$|\s|[.!?:;])`.

Comment: right you are, that's probably the better approach, actually.

Answer (score 2):

`match` isn't really the right tool for the job here.  Each item will need additional parsing or trimming, so you're better off just using `exec` from the start with a while loop.

```
var match,
    tags = [],
    str = "*aaa *eee *rrr *ttt",
    reg = /(?:\s|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})\b/gim;

while (match = reg.exec(str))
    tags.push(match[1]);

console.log(tags)
//-> ["*aaa", "*eee", "*rrr", "*ttt"]
```

Note that in the regular expression, `\b` means word boundary, and `(?:\s|^)` means match but do not capture `\s` or `^`.  The latter ensures that `match[1]` will always be the tag.

Comment: where did you test?
i got a: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?:\s|^)(\*([a-z0-9]{3,150})\b/: Unterminated group

Comment: @jbd it works, I just put an extra bracket in by mistake ;-) try it now

Comment: In your regex, the `\b` changes the result slightly from the OP. Instead of capturing the first 150 characters of a very long string the \b forces the string to be 150 characters or less. I don't disagree with the use, rather I wanted to call attention to the subtlety as it may be useful depending on the requester's use case.

Comment: @Denomales: it does change the result, but only in making it more consistent (ie, eliminating white space capture) and increasing the chances of a match where punctuation is following :-) In the OP, the `{3,150}` is followed by `(\s|$)`, which also forces the `[a-z0-9]` match to be 150 characters or less.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the regex as `/(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})/img`

See it in action: http://regexr.com?35ae3

EDIT: Following @AndyE suggestion, the regex could be written as `/(?:\s+|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})/img`, http://regexr.com?35aec

Comment: I'd assume the reason for the `\s` matches is so as not to accidentally match 'aaa*bbb'.

Comment: Problem is: "*aaa *eee *rrr@ *ttt".match(/(?:\s+|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})/img)
match with *rrr@ => while it should not because it contains a non wanted one: @

Comment: @jbdemonte actually the additional `@` causes no problem, see http://regexr.com?35anr

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the space is getting consumed by the previous match and thus unavailable for the current match.

You can use look-ahead - `(?=\s|$)` instead of `(\s|$)`. Try:

```
(\s|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(?=\s|$)
```

See [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for more on look-ahead.

[Test](http://regexr.com?35ae6).

But in this case you can remove the check for the following space altogether, since `[a-z0-9]` can't match a space. Following from this, another option is changing it to: (if this fits your requirements)

```
(\s|^)(\*[^\s]{3,150})
```

`[^\s]` means not white-space.

Comment: i though look-ahead was not available on web regex, i'll look deeper, thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's ok!

    "*aaa *eee *rrr *ttt".match(/(?:\s|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(?=\s|$)/img)

lookahead was the right solution

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `\s` from your regex.  You are grabbing the beginning and ending space so when you get to `*eee` there is no beginning space.

`(\s|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(|$)`

Example:

http://regexr.com?35ae0

**EDIT**

You can also leave in the `\s` by adding `{0,}` after it, which means it will look for any length of white space.

`/(\s{0,}|^)(\*[a-z0-9]{3,150})(\s{0,}|$)/gim`

Example: http://regexr.com?35ae9